# How do translate the following to swift?

Tags: facebook, swift

I'm new to swift,before posting my question, I tried on my own, but i failed to get this property translated to Swift:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user;
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. Could you clarify what you tried, and what error you get.

Comment: This is not an error, just not familiar with new language swift. Just needed to know how to translate the above property to swift.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [great tutorial](http://www.iphonelife.com/blog/31369/swift-101-classes-variables-properties-methods) on defining classes in Swift, which shows the same syntax for declaring a property on a class.

You can't have a generic dictionary with only a single item closing the generic type. You need to define the key and value types for the dictionary. Perhaps you meant to define an array?

`var users: Array<FBGraphUser>`

or if you want a [dictionary keyed by a string](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Dictionary.html):

`var users: Dictionary<String, FBGraphUser>`

Comment: Are you sure you're properly importing the Facebook header? This is straight out of the language spec